# How to make Update Manager update programs I've installed?

Tags: updates, update-manager

I have installed Chromium, Lightspark and Gnash on my Ubuntu system. I want to make Update Manager update these programs without asking me, and always search to find updates.

Comment: How did you install them? From source tarballs, or from the repositories (Software Center, apt-get, Synaptic, etc)?

Comment: apt-get for chromuim and gnash. I did apt-get for light spark I also did update and respiratories

Answer (score 1):

Chromium tends to update itself automatically, silently, or whenever a new package for it comes out.

With Gnash, it gets updated whenever a new package for it is released.  When that happens, Update Manager will update it.  Otherwise, it won't, because there's no new updates.

Answer (score 0):

If you have already added the PPA or other software repository for the mentioned programs then your Ubuntu update manager will find and inform you of any updates available for those programs in accordance to your update settings (daily, two-daily, weekly etc.).

Comment: how do I get the PPA? and how do I check if I do?